# O que seria Pro*C/C++?

Tags: c, c++, oracle, stored-procedures

Pelo o que vi ele é utilizando no Oracle, Mas posso utilizar com outro Banco?

Pro*C/C++ é útil no dias atuais?

Poderia passar um Exemplo de código?

Ele tem diferença do PL/SQL? Ou são utilizado em conjunto?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> O que seria Pro*C/C++?

Um mecanismo que permite usar essas linguagens dentro do banco de dados como se fossem códigos PL/SQL. Pode dar algum ganho de performance e permitir algoritmos mais poderosos que seria difícil fazer na linguagem do Oracle. Muitas vezes é usado só para performance, tanto que ele pode compilar o SQL em um código C para ser usado.

O ganho muitas vezes ocorre porque não ter mais que ficar interpretando. Mas pode ser maior quando você mexe no código gerado otimizando algo que o otimizador do Oracle não consegue. É uma API suportada e deixa você fazer o que quiser.

[Documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/LNPCC/toc.htm).

> Pro*C/C++ é útil no dias atuais?

É útil sim. Nunca foi de enorme utilidade, mas ainda pode ser interessante aqui ou ali.

É claro que se você é desenvolvedor e não um DBA tenderá a considerar que essas melhorias deveriam estar na aplicação e não no banco de dados. Se é um DBA em geral não mexerá com C. Mas algum consulta otimizada ainda é útil.

> Poderia passar um Exemplo de código?

```
/* ... */
for (;;) {
    printf("Give student id number : ");
    scanf("%d", &id);
    EXEC SQL WHENEVER NOT FOUND GOTO notfound;
    EXEC SQL SELECT studentname INTO :st_name
             FROM   student
             WHERE  studentid = :id;
    printf("Name of student is %s.\n", st_name);
    continue;
notfound:
    printf("No record exists for id %d!\n", id);
}
/* ... */
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/IO/ProCOracleSQL.c)

[Fonte](http://infolab.stanford.edu/%7Eullman/fcdb/oracle/or-proc.html).

> Ele tem diferença do PL/SQL? Ou são utilizado em conjunto?

Podem ser usados em conjunto. A API permite fazer tudo o que dá para fazer no PL/SQL, mas de uma forma bem diferente. Na verdade a linguagem C ou C++ junto com a API substitui a PL/SQL nas partes que você quiser.